# Enable ipv6 forwarding in docker container

Tags: docker, networking, ipv6

Im trying to setup a firewall for IPv6 between two networks using Docker (I know there are other technologies to do this, but I want to use docker). The main problem that I ran into is that I can not find a way to enable the IPv6 forwarding inside the firewall container.

From the dockerd reference[1] I know that there are options to enable this for IPv4, but there are none for IPv6. Is this feature simply not supported yet, or am I doing something wrong?

My daemon.json looks like this:

```
{
  "ipv6": true,
  "fixed-cidr-v6": "2001:db8:1::/64",
  "ip-forward": true
}
```

[1] https://docs.docker.com/engine/reference/commandline/dockerd/

Answer (score 1, accepted):

in your docker-compose.yml add:

```
sysctls:
  net.ipv6.conf.all.disable_ipv6: 0
  net.ipv6.conf.all.forwarding: 1
```

Answer (score 0):

This worked for me after I modified my `/etc/docker/daemon.json` to contain `experimental` and `ip6tables`, like so:

```
{
    "ipv6": true,
    "experimental": true,
    "ip6tables": true,
    "fixed-cidr-v6": "fd07:a:b:c::/64",
    ...
}
```